# How to work around the broken removeAttribute in IE/Edge?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to remember the selected item of a select or multi-select form element in a `contenteditable` block. For Firefox and Chrome, I can just remember the selected item(s), remove the `selected` attributes and tag the ones that should have it. Normal DOM serialization will take care of the rest.
Trying to do this with IE or Edge fails miserable, since it just doesn't work. The following is a small test case:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <select multiple>
    <option id="op1" selected value="1">1</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="var op1 = getElementById('op1'); op1.removeAttribute('selected'); alert(op1.outerHTML);">Test </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have a method that works without having to clone the options that have the attribute and replacing the current nodes with them? Target would be IE 8+ and Edge; older IE is not of interest.

Comment: Could you try `op1.selected = false`? It seems to work, but somehow the UI only updates after hovering the select box for me...

Comment: That helps a bit. IE 11 drops the attribute, Edge doesn't. I remembering trying that earlier, but only in Edge.

Comment: Have you tried `op1.selected = false`? Given that the attribute initialises the property but isn’t updated to reflect the current state of the element during/after user interaction I’d imagine it’s the way to go in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the suggestion from user3297291, a follow-up search found [Issue #12087679 for Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12087679/). Integrating the suggestions from that gives the following, which works in all of IE11, Edge, Chrome and Firefox:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <select multiple>
    <option id="op1" selected value="1">1</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="var op1 = getElementById('op1');
                   op1.setAttribute('selected', false);
                   op1.selected = false;
                   op1.removeAttribute('selected');
                   alert(op1.outerHTML);">Test </button>
</body>
</html>
```

First, explicitly ensure that the attribute is a boolean value, the default is not (Edge bug). Next, disable the property to make Microsoft browsers also remove the attribute. Finally, remove the attribute for the rest of the world that implements DOM level 1.

Comment: Bravo! Just cleared over a dozen Edge-specific bugs from the backlog.

Comment: Hmm. After I went to the trouble of getting that MS issue (#12087679) linked from caniuse, MS has gone and removed the page, so it's now a 404! I assume this is because they have switched to blink/chromium and the bug will 'disappear' - but I assume the bug will still be there on IE, and non-updated Edge installations. Can anyone clarify?